# C#: how to pass mathematical function from textbox to function

Tags: c#, function, string-parsing

I have a textbox where i want to read user-input mathematical functions( ex: Math.Sqrt(x) etc).

The code I've been using for console testing the function is

```
    static double f(double x)
    {
        double f;
        f = Math.Sqrt(x);
        return f;
    }
```

I'm not sure how to modify it: do I read the textbox contents in a string, and add that string as a second argument to the f function ( static double f(double x, string s)? what type of parsing should I apply to the string?

Comment: Does the user always enter C#-compiling arithmetics and math?

Comment: you can google for "C# equation parser"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are [several formula parsers](http://www.codeproject.com/search.aspx?q=formula%20parser&doctypeid=1) out there that you can use.

Basically you need someone/something that evaluates your formula.

I'm using [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13779/The-expression-evaluator-revisited-Eval-function-i) successfully in my own projects. It allows for calling it like

```
var ev = 
    new Eval3.Evaluator(
        Eval3.eParserSyntax.c,/*caseSensitive*/ 
        false);

MessageBox.Show(ev.Parse("1+2+3").value.ToString());
```

What I would *not* recommend to use is the [dynamic compilation of C# code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.csharp.csharpcodeprovider.aspx) since it adds each compiled code to your application domain ("app domain") and there is no option to unload it again. (Correct me, if I'm wrong).

Comment: thank you, dunno why I didn't think of searching for something like this. I'll give the parser a shot, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Another evaluator: http://csharp-eval.com/

Answer (score 0):

If your interested in how to get the text from the textbox and do something with the value the following code will do that for you. If you want to enter a function in the textbox - sqrt(40) you should check this project: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23061/MathParser-Math-Formula-Parser

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.aspx

```
static double f(Textbox tb)
{
    double f;
    double x = Double.Parse(tb.Text);
    f = Math.Sqrt(x);
    return f;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can execute arbitrary code, but not easily. For general code you must create a wrapper class and insert the code into a function.

Take a look at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/6a783cc4-bb54-4fec-b504-f9b1ed786b54/